# LibreOffice on OS X: running soffice keeps saying no Info.plist or no NSPrincipalClass in Info.plist

Tags: macos, mac, shell, libreoffice

I'm trying to run LibreOffice 5.1.3 from the OS X terminal, to script some conversion tasks.

However whenever I run `soffice`, I always get this error:

`No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`

No matter the directory from where I run it. I've also tried the dir containing LibreOffice.app, or its Contents/ dir (which does contain a Info.plist file, by the way) or the MacOS/ or bin/ dirs within there. All to no avail.

Note that `soffice -h` does work, it gives me the help with all the command line options.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually looked pretty hard for this after both a full install and a `brew cask install` of libreoffice gave the same error. I found the answer in a comment on [Github](https://gist.github.com/psjinx/3ad78df6290b5ba931c1).

Seems libreoffice gives this `Info.plist` error in calling soffice via a symlink.  Calling soffice directly via `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice` or by making a small shell script in `/usr/local/bin` fixes it.

Comment: This worked well for me. Specifically your script might look something like this: ```#!/bin/bash
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice $@```

Comment: This almost worked perfectly. My 1 cent collaboration is just to wrap _$@_ with double quotes like this ```"$@"```

Answer (score 0):

I could not use soffice using the full path.  I got the same error.  I had to `cd` into the directory before I ran it with `./soffice`.

```
$cd ~
$ /Applications/OpenOffice.app/Contents/program/soffice -h
2017-07-14 11:41:59.329 soffice[32094:4999526] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting

$ cd /Applications/OpenOffice.app/Contents/program
$ ./soffice -help
```

OpenOffice 4.1.3  413m1(Build:9783)