# LibreOffice OS X: converting a .odt to .pdf from terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell, pdf, libreoffice

Using LibreOffice, I can open an ODT document and export it as PDF manually.

Is there also a command line do to this from the shell?

Answer (score 9):

`/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf my_document.odt`

It requires that Libre Office is closed in order to process fine. It's a known [bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37531&redirected_from=fdo).

Edit: Bug seems fixed in LO 5.3

Comment: Confirmed, the bug has been fixed. I installed 5.3, then update it to 5.4

Answer (score 3):

`loffice` is the command you are looking for.

Here is a snippet from the output I got after running `loffice --help`

```
--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name[:output_filter_options]] [--outdir output_dir] files
  Batch convert files (implies --headless).
  If --outdir is not specified then current working dir is used as output_dir.
  Eg. --convert-to pdf *.doc
      --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
      --convert-to "html:XHTML Writer File:UTF8" *.doc
      --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" *.doc
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do `loffice` I get: `-bash: loffice: command not found`. I tried locating `loffice` to see if I maybe should run that from within a specific path, but Spotlight doesn't find any file called `loffice`. I've got the latest LibreOffice version (currently v5.1.3.2).

Comment: Actually, maybe you meant `soffice`? That does exist, and `soffice --help` gives me a whole bunch of help options (also mentioning `--convert-to`). But when I try `soffice --convert-to pdf example.odt` I get: `2016-06-07 10:51:28.733 soffice[36674:2153112] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`,  see also [this topic](http://superuser.com/questions/1078968/libreoffice-on-os-x-running-soffice-keeps-saying-no-info-plist-or-no-nsprincipa)

Comment: I wasn't aware the name of the binaries differed across platforms (I'm on ArchLinux). I don't have much experience with OS X so I can help you with the message you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the .odt file on the terminal thought the `soffice` command on the /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/ path.

If you are using a system that requires `lowriter`, you can create a link for the file /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice to the lowriter like:

```
#cd /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/ && ln -s soffice lowriter
```

After that, you can add the /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/ to the system path, by adding the path above to the file `/etc/paths` (to avoid the error  `No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`):

```
cd /etc && echo '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/' >> paths
```

Now you can call:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /path_to/output_dir/ /path_to_file/file_name.odt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a totally different approach.

It works (as explicitely required) on the command line. It does NOT use (as maybe implicitely expected) LibreOffice at all, but some other software, namely **[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)** (plus some more).

It is possible, because in recent times a series of new conversion paths were opened by Pandoc's newly acquired capability to read ODT files.

When Pandoc reads in a file format, it converts it into an internal format, "native" (which is a form of JSON).

From its native form, it can then export the document into a whole range of other formats. Not only PDF, but also DocBook, HTML, EPUB, DOCX, ASCIIdoc, DokuWiki, MediaWiki and what-not...

Since here the wanted output format is PDF, we have another choice of different paths, provided by what Pandoc is calling a *pdf-engine*. Here is the list of currently available PDF engines (valid for Pandoc v2.7.2 and later -- previous versions may support only a smaller list):

- **pdflatex:** This requires *[LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **xelatex:** This requires *XeLaTeX* to be installed in addition to Pandoc (also available as an additional package to general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **context:** This requires *ConTeXt* to be installed in addition to Pandoc; ConTeXt is available as an additional package to most general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **lualatex:** This requires *[LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/download.html)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc (also available as an additional package to general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **pdfroff:** This requires *[GNU Roff](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/#downloading)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **wkhtml2pdf:** This requires *[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **prince:** This requires *[PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **weasyprint:** This requires *[weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.

There are some more and newer PDF engines now integrated into Pandoc, which I have not yet used myself and which I currently cannot describe in more detail: *[tectonic](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5345)* and *[latexmk](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3195)*.

**WARNING:** Do not expect that the appearance of your original document will be identical in all the PDF outputs to the print preview or PDF export of the ODT! Pandoc, when converting ***does not preserve layouts***, it preserves the ***contents*** and the ***structure*** of documents: paragraphs remain paragraphs, emphasized words remain emphasized, headings remain headings, etc. But the overall look can change considerably.

#### Example commands

**pdflatex:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=pdflatex
```

**XeLaTeX:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

**LuaLaTeX:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=lualatex
```

**ConTeXt:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=context
```

**GNU troff:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=pdfroff
```

**wkhtmltopdf:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=wkhtml2pdf
```

**PrinceXML:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=prince
```

**weasyprint:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=weasyprint
```

Above commands are the most basic for the conversion. Depending on the PDF engine you pick, there may be many other options possible to control the appearance of the output PDF file. For example, the following additional parameters may be added to all those paths routing through LaTeX:

```
 -V geometry:"paperwidth=23.3cm, paperheight=1000pt, margin=11.2mm, top=2cm"
```

which will use a custom page size (a bit larger than DIN A4) with margins of 2cm on the top edge and 1.12cm at the other three edges).

Answer (score 0):

###### Install

```bsh
brew install --cask libreoffice
```

###### Convert

```bsh
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt
```